# How to solve : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

How to solve : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Real(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


>>> from real.models import Real
>>> list = Real.objects.all()
>>> list
<QuerySet [<Real: Umair Khan>, <Real: Uzair Khan>, <Real: Anas>]>
>>> list.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the field in the model is not possible for Queryset, but for Model instance. So try this:

```
    for real in list:
        print(real.name)
```

Or if you want the list of names, then try this:

```
    [real for real in list.values('name')]
```

This will return the list of dictionary i.e.

```
    [ {'name': name}, ...]
```